# Asp.Net Website project with 'add view' tooling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are many posts on this, most of which suggest adding the MVC project type GUID to the .*proj file.

THe website project model doesn't have a project file though, so is there some way to get support for the add view dialog and tooling with a hybrid website / MVC project?

Comment: If you **application** is a typeof **web site**, then you will have no use of ASP.NET MVC I think. Why do you need the tooling?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by no use? I am hoping to get integrated tooling because it streamlines a lot of the plumbing in generating a view (model binding etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve what you want in a WebSite (at least not currently). The Add Controller functionality is implemented as a VSPackage that gets loaded when the MVC project type GUID is detected (that's why all the other posts mention it).

Comment: ah well, hold thumbs for a service pack I suppose. Thanks

Comment: In Mvc 4 we will be introducing the concept of recipes (extensible framework for actions that can be performed on your project) and we will reimplement Add Controller using it. There could conceivably run in WebSites though we are not explicitly targetting that scenario